# First word starts with a particular character that is not blacklisted

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I have the following example list:

```
abanana
apple
aubergine
bcarrot
berry
bpineapple
date
```

I'd like a regex expression that would replace the `a` or `b` at the beginning of any line except `apple`, `aubergine` or `berry`. I'm using Google Sheets find and replace (which uses the [RE2 engine](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax)).

In the example above, it should match:

```
abanana
bcarrot
bpineapple
```

I've tried this:

> ^(?=a|b)(?!apple|aubergine|berry)

which matches the right sequences but doesn't **"return"** the first letter (which Google Sheets can then replace).

Here's what this looks like in Google Sheets:

[image: Google Sheets: Search and Replace]

Comment: *a and b* - you meant `a` OR `b`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest you're right, fixed.

Comment: in this case we want to replace `a` or `b` with what? (I just wanted to work with real condition/input while finding the answer)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest the "Find" part of the task would be concerned with matching the a / b. The "Replace" part would be left empty, so the character would be deleted. See: https://snag.gy/E2kMoB.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following regex:

`^(?!apple|aubergine|berry)(a|b)`

- `^(?!apple|aubergine|berry` - assuring that the current word is not on the exclusion list
- `(a|b)` matching the needed character to replace

https://regex101.com/r/0A35mi/1

Comment: I think that should work since it is not RE2 that is used in S&R in Google spreadsheets, it is JS regex flavor allowing lookaheads.